# Speed up CI process in Gitlab

Tags: performance, continuous-integration, gitlab, node-modules

I am very new with Gitlab and I don't know how to set up it properly. I want to know how can we speed up the process CI in Gitlab because currently my project took up to 20m to finish the process of checking, building, and deploying.

I believe the reason is because each job make another run for `npm install` or `yarn install`. I defined the cache as follow but it didn't speed up the process:

```
cache:
 key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
 paths:
   - node_modules/
```

the first image I am using is `docket:git`, should I change it to another image so I can run `npm install` in `before_script`? Or there is other way to speed up gitlab ci process?

**EDIT**:
Add gitlab-ci.yml file, I removed some sensitive information, basically, it is the same with the one I used

```
image: docker:git

stages:
- build
- build-image
- build-staging
- build-image-staging
- build-production
- build-image-production
- release
- checkstyle #TO move up
- test #To move up
- deploy

variables:
  CONTAINER_IMAGE: registry
  HOST: ""
  IP: ""
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

before_script:
  - git checkout -B "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" "$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
  - echo "CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME = "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  - BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && echo "BRANCH = "$BRANCH
  - ID=$(git rev-list --count $BRANCH) && echo "ID = "$ID
  - TAG=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags || true) && echo "TAG = "$TAG
  - REGISTRY=$CONTAINER_IMAGE":"$ID"_"$BRANCH
  - DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
  - echo $'\n\n----------\n'"REGISTRY = "$REGISTRY$'\n'"COMMIT   = "$CI_COMMIT_SHA$'\n'"BRANCH   = "$BRANCH$'\n'"DATE     = "$DATE$'\n----------\n\n'
#  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.example.com

cache:
 key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
 paths:
   - node_modules/

analysis-lint:
  image: node:latest
  stage: checkstyle
  script:
    - npm install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng lint --type-check


build-integration:
  stage: build
  image: node
  script:
    - yarn install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build ---prod --configuration=integration --aot --output-hashing all --source-map=false
    - npm run webpack:server
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
  only:
    - develop

build-testing:
  stage: build
  image: node
  script:
    - yarn install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build ---prod --configuration=testing --aot --output-hashing all --source-map=false
    - npm run webpack:server
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
  only:
    - /^release.*$/

build-staging:
  stage: build-staging
  image: node
  script:
    - yarn install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build ---prod --configuration=staging --aot --output-hashing all --source-map=false
    - npm run webpack:server
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
  only:
    - /^hotfix.*$/
    - master

build-production:
  stage: build-production
  image: node
  script:
    - yarn install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build ---prod --configuration=production --aot --output-hashing all --source-map=false
    - npm run webpack:server
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
  only:
    - master

build-image-integration:
  stage: build-image
  script:
    - docker build -t $REGISTRY-integration -f Dockerfile --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=integration .
    - docker push $REGISTRY-integration
  only:
    - develop
    - universal

build-image-testing:
  stage: build-image
  script:
    - docker build -t $REGISTRY-testing -f Dockerfile --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=testing .
    - docker push $REGISTRY-testing
  only:
    - /^release.*$/

build-image-staging:
  stage: build-image-staging
  script:
    - docker build -t $REGISTRY-staging -f Dockerfile --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=staging .
    - docker push $REGISTRY-staging
  only:
    - /^hotfix.*$/
    - master

build-image-production:
  stage: build-image-production
  script:
    - docker build -t $REGISTRY-production -f Dockerfile --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=production .
    - docker push $REGISTRY-production
  only:
    - master

release-image-integration:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $REGISTRY-integration
    - docker tag $REGISTRY-integration $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$BRANCH
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$BRANCH
  only:
    - develop
    - universal

release-image-testing:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $REGISTRY-testing
    - docker tag $REGISTRY-testing $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$BRANCH
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$BRANCH
    - docker tag $REGISTRY-testing $CONTAINER_IMAGE:release
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:release
  only:
    - /^release.*$/

release-image-staging:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $REGISTRY-staging
    - docker tag $REGISTRY-staging $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$BRANCH-staging
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$BRANCH-staging
  only:
    - /^hotfix.*$/
    - master

release-image-master:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $REGISTRY-production
    - docker tag $REGISTRY-production $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$BRANCH
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$BRANCH
  only:
    - master

release-image-latest:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $REGISTRY-production
    - docker tag $REGISTRY-production $CONTAINER_IMAGE:latest
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:latest
    - docker tag $REGISTRY-production $CONTAINER_IMAGE
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE
  only:
    - master

release-image-production:
  stage: release
  script:
    - if [ ! -z "$TAG" ]; then docker pull $REGISTRY-production;docker tag $REGISTRY-production $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$TAG;docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$TAG;fi;
  only:
    - master
    #- /^release.*$/
    #- /^hotfix.*$/

development:
  stage: deploy
  image: appropriate/curl
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to development server"
    - curl
  environment:
    name: development
    url:
  before_script: []
  when: manual
  only:
    - develop

integration-universal:
  stage: deploy
  image: appropriate/curl
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to integration server"
    - curl
  environment:
    name: integration
    url:
  before_script: []
  when: manual
  only:
    - universal

integration:
  stage: deploy
  image: appropriate/curl
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to integration server"
    - curl
  environment:
    name: integration
    url:
  before_script: []
  when: manual
  only:
    - develop

testing:
  stage: deploy
  image: appropriate/curl
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to testing server"
    - curl
  environment:
    name: testing
    url:
  before_script: []
  when: manual
  only:
    - /^release.*$/

staging:
  stage: deploy
  image: appropriate/curl
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to staging server"
    - curl
  environment:
    name: staging
    url:
  before_script: []
  when: manual
  only:
    - /^release.*$/
    - /^hotfix.*$/
    - master

production:
  stage: deploy
  image: appropriate/curl
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to production server"
    - curl
  environment:
    name: production
    url:
  before_script: []
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: We could help you more efficiently if you posted larger parts, ideally all of your .gitlab-ci.yml file. There are many aspects than can help speed up the GitLab CI process.

Comment: @ThomasKainrad I just added it, can you take a look

Answer (score 2):

Without having seen the `Dockerfile`, it is still relatively safe to safe to say that the majority of time is spent building docker images.

Why would you need to have 4 different stages that execute `docker build`? You should get this down to exactly one. You can still pull the built image in other stages for testing and integration. I see that you are building the containers with different `--build-arg`s. However, what is the point of building a special image for testing? You should test your production image.

Another thing would be looking at parallelization. GitLab CI executes jobs of the same stage in parallel. Some of your jobs seem to not depend on the previous one. Why not execute them in the same stage?

Further, I do not fully understand your `before_script`. Why do you need to `git checkout`? Gitlab CI will automatically checkout your current commit's branch.